# Is Express.js necessary in learning Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

Most books on Node.js have Express.js sections. Most Node tutorials I've seen are about web development with Node and Express. So, is the knowledge of Express required for a deep understanding of Node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It isn't,

ExpressJs is framework build on top of nodejs, as they are many framework in different programming language it is the same for Javascript in the backend side.

Here is some of example of Framework

- [Loopback](https://loopback.io/)
- [Sails.js](https://sailsjs.com/)
- [Koa](https://koajs.com/)
- [Express](http://expressjs.com/)

In the nodejs world ExpressJS is the popular one, so in many books it's normal to talk about It, as Javascript was firstly build for the web.

But NodeJS can be use for so many kind of application like

- Data Streaming Apps
- Server-Side Proxy
- Big Data Analytics
- Wireless Connectivity
- System Monitoring Dashboard
- Chatbots

And other many sort of application.

In the web world ExpressJS is the popular one.

So you don't have to learn ExpressJS to deep undestand nodejs. And you don't have to learn it if you would not build web application or API. You can also rely packages shiped with nodejs to build any sort of application even web application but it will take you more time than using existing package.]

You can search for any sort of package at **[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/)**

Answer (score 1):

no, a framework is never necessary to learn the language but the opposite, Learning the language is absolutely necessary to learn the framework.

According to express.js: "Express is a minimal and flexible Node.js web application framework that provides a robust set of features for web and mobile applications." thats all.